# WebAPI only partially decoding URL Encoded string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

So I'm writing a REST app using WebAPI on ASP.NET. I'm stumbling across a problem.

On PHP I'm using the urlencode function which results in

The original base64 encoded string is

`kA+1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3/WubyGTc=`

On PHP after running it through urlencode I get :- 
`kA%2B1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3%2FWubyGTc%3D`

Following this debugging, I checked fiddler and indeed its sending over the correct URLEncoded string...

Now when it gets to ASP.NET MVC WebAPI I get  :-

`kA+1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3/WubyGTc%3`

So it looks like WebAPI or MVC is trying to do some pre-cursive url-decoding by itself, however its got two problems with it :-

- It is only partially decoding the string, so the + and / sign get converted correctly but the = doesn't
- It appears to be truncating the D from %3D which results in %3 which isn't a valid URL Character.

Has anyone experienced this issue before? To replicate it, simply create a web app with

```
public TokenAPI Get(Guid caller, Guid id, string ip, string signature, Guid eventID)
{
}
```

And pass in the values

`/api/GenerateToken?id=d9a2057c-c228-40d4-a9a9-5d7a4da4984b&caller=e1af32bb-ac84-4f45-b4d6-67f7543ffab2&ip=127.0.0.1&eventID=f6d71c3d-ef00-41e1-8dec-a3a77bdf7484&signature=kA%2B1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3%2FWubyGTc%3D`

Then inspect the signature parameter, and you'll find its only partially URLDecoded by itself...

Any pointers would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to reproduce this with ASP.NET MVC 4 RC.

Steps:

1. Create a new empty ASP.NET MVC 4 application
2. Add an API controller:

   ```
   public class ValuesController : ApiController
   {
       public string Get(Guid caller, Guid id, string ip, string signature, Guid eventID)
       {
           return signature;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Navigate to `/api/values?id=d9a2057c-c228-40d4-a9a9-5d7a4da4984b&caller=e1af32bb-ac84-4f45-b4d6-67f7543ffab2&ip=127.0.0.1&eventID=f6d71c3d-ef00-41e1-8dec-a3a77bdf7484&signature=kA%2B1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3%2FWubyGTc%3D`
4. Result:

   ```
   <string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">kA+1n8i00qcJPNgPUXq8YqerScbQOw5Hvb3/WubyGTc=</string>
   ```

The `signature` parameter is correctly url decoded.

Comment: Ugh, ok thanks @DarinDimitrov I'll try and figure out whats going on then. Remove all filters etc etc will post back any findings.